# Error "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate", referenced from:" and error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)"

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode

I'm pretty new to developing, and i got this error, I'm not shire if i got something missing in my AppDelegate files so I'm gonna show you the files.

**the h-file**

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>


@interface AppDelegate: UIResponder <UIApplicationDelegate>


@property (strong, nonatomic)  UIWindow *window;

@end
```

**the m-file**

```
#import "AppDelegate.h"
```

the thing is that i think i removed something from te m-file but i can't remember what it was

here is the full error message:

**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_AppDelegate", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in main.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)**

Comment: the error message are now posted

Comment: @implementation AppDelegate is this there in .m file

Comment: that was the problem xphobia, thanks!

Comment: @Andy I am getting error. may I know how to could you resolve it?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

You will need to make sure that your `AppDelegate.m` is added under Compile Sources in your target settings.

To do this, click on the project (left upper on your Xcode window) -> Click on **Build Phases** tab -> **Compile Sources** and then check to see whether `AppDelegate.m` is actually added to the list. If not, click + button -> Type `AppDelegate.m` -> Select and then **Add** it. That should do.

Comment: thanks, but the AppDelegate.m are added to the Compile Sources, but it docent work

Comment: i forgotten the interface AppDelegate in my m.file. oh i mean the implementation ofc ;)

Comment: saved my day.feeling happy

Comment: AppDelegate.m is already in that list but still getting error. This is happening only while archiving. Any alternatives to try?

Comment: This happened to me in 2022 after upgrading to React Native 0.68.2 because AppDelegate.m was removed and AppDelegate.mm was added. I followed your advice and added AppDelegate.mm instead and it solved the problem for me.

Comment: Its already there , any other solutions for RN 0.62