# Linker error when converting Obj-c iOS app to Swift

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift

I have an iOS app written in Objective-C that I want to convert to Swift. Per Apple's [Using Swift with Cocoa and Objective-C](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/BuildingCocoaApps/Migration.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014216-CH12-XID_69), I added a new Swift file with the same name as the Objective-C class it's replacing, put in a stub class declaration, and removed the original Objective-C class from the target.

The error is reporting that a symbol for the class can't be found at link time:

```
Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64:
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_Chunk", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in ViewController.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

Here's my stub class declaration:

```
import Foundation

@objc class Chunk {

}
```

Is there some linker setting I can check?

And yes, I have cleaned my project, removed my derived data folder, and [confirmed that the Swift file is in the Compile Sources section of the Build Phases](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25908604/error-objc-class-appdelegate-referenced-from-and-error-linker-command-f).

I've also now reproduced the problem with a brand new project created in Xcode 6.1.1, available at https://github.com/dpassage/Foo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your link (Apple Dev)... you must check again "Importing Swift into Objective-C" :)

In your `ViewController.m`... remove this line: `#import "Chunk.h"`
and add this line:     `#import "Foo-Swift.h"`

"The file:`<#YourProjectName#>-Swift.h` should already be created automatically in your project, even if you can not see it."

**UPDATE**

If Chunk.swift is descendant of an Objective-C class.. replace this `@objc class Chunk` with this: `@objc class Chunk : NSObject` (or conf with your requirement).
If not... check "Using PURE Swift Classes in Objective-C" from here https://stackoverflow.com/a/24005242/1702413

Comment: Thanks, Tony! Totally confusing that changing an include file fixes a *linker* error...